# Making column share row, but only on mobile. Image is attached illustrating. Not possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to play around for a while now with Bootstrap, but this issue does seem unsolvable to me.

See the attached image below. The columns are marked with numbers, so illustrate where they move.

Is this not possible?

I've tried and achieved the left part of the image. But I cannot solve how to on mobile have it look like on the image.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: I don't know how to say it better. I'm not even sure how to describe it with words. That's why I included the image. Why is an image for description not enough for StackOverflow? I'm asking for help in a very graphically/illustration kind of question. Just like I would rather get an reply showing the code / illustration it, then just someone explaining it...

Comment: It's not just about describing the issue.  You have not even provided a [mcve] - please read the guidelines in the three links I've posted. Then, comeback and improve your question - Help us, help you!

Comment: Also, it's either bootstrap 3 or 4 (not both) - clean up your tags while you are editing the question

Comment: No, it's both. Because what ever version of bootstrap that solves this, I want to use! And I'm pretty sure, both columns system would mark it up very similar, only change would possibly be the syntax, but I'm interested in if it's possible to have this kind of design with the bootstrap (3 or 4) column system.

Comment: I haven't tried anything that is of importance, because I cannot wrap my head around how to do this.

But sure, I'll play along with you. I've tried the left image. That's what I've achived.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 'playing along with me' - it's about the guidelines for good questions.  We are not here to write code for you.  Go ahead and give it a go! try it yourself, maybe you'll figure it out!!!!

Comment: oh, btw, yes it is possible to do such layout